# Stop Wampserver allowing folder indexes

Tags: permissions, hosting, directory, wampserver

Just a simple question but I can't seem to find an answer.

I want to have Wampserver hosting a site (I am aware of the security implications of home hosting, don't worry), and I want to stop people accessing the index of folders and viewing all the files. For example, I want mysite/images not to be browsable, but I'd like for the files to be accessible, for example, mysite/images/image1.jpg.

My current virtual host for said website:

```
<VirtualHost *:25567>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Tom\OFFICIAL_WEBSERVERwamp\www\25567" 
    <Directory "C:\Users\Tom\OFFICIAL_WEBSERVERwamp\www\25567">
 AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Remove the indexes part..? You might want to make it specific to the images directory if that us the only one you don't want to display the contents of? Changes to the configuration require and apache reload of course

Comment: Ah of course! I understand it now. First time running a server online!